# Query Execution Statistics for Parallelized Collections in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

When computing statistics for a simple parallelized collection in Spark 2.3.0 I'm getting some strange results:

```
val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq("y")).toDF("y")
df.queryExecution.stringWithStats

== Optimized Logical Plan 
== Project [value#7 AS y#9], Statistics(sizeInBytes=8.0 EB, hints=none)
+- SerializeFromObject [staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, input[0, java.lang.String, true], true, false) AS value#7], Statistics(sizeInBytes=8.0 EB, hints=none)    
+- ExternalRDD [obj#6], Statistics(sizeInBytes=8.0 EB, hints=none)
```

That is 8.0 Exabytes of data.

If I do the equivalent without parallelizing

```
== Optimized Logical Plan 
== LocalRelation [x#3], Statistics(sizeInBytes=20.0 B, hints=none)
```

Clearly when the collection is getting serialized there is a side effect that the query planner can't accurately figure out the size.  Am I missing something here?